# to find the duplicates in a string in java

Tags: java

im working on a question where i need to find the duplicates in a given string. i am able to do it but im not able to output it the the series of alphabet with respect to the input string.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class SandroBook {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "";
    String y = "";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
    x=in.next();
    if (x.length()>=1 && x.length()<=50 && x.equals(x.toLowerCase())) {
        y=x;
    }
    char[] c = y.toCharArray();
    for(Character ch:c){
          if(map.containsKey(ch)){
             map.put(ch, map.get(ch)+1);
          } else {
             map.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }
    Set<Character> keys = map.keySet();
    for(Character ch:keys){
          if(map.get(ch) > 1){
            sb.append(ch);
          }
        }
     System.out.println(sb.toString());
    in.close();
}

}
```

output expected:

```
String by user: tebidohtebidoh
output: tebidoh
```

output im getting:

```
String by user: tebidohtebidoh
output: detbohi
```

kindly help on how can i output it in the same format with respect to the input.

Comment: are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hashmap, use LinkedHashMap. So change your line here:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

To

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

HashMap will apply the hash function on hashCode and will store the data in random bucket and hence when iterating over the hashMap you wont get the way you inserted the element into map. While in LinkedHashMap you will iterate over the map the way you inserted elements in the map.

Comment: thank you. i got to know the difference now. this was  helpful.